# Deploying React (3000) and Express (8000) app on the apache server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have created a React+Express application using the commands `npx create-react-app client` for React and `npx express-generator api` for the express backend. Both client and API are under the same folder `application`.

The react application is running on the port 3000 and I have changed the port of express app to use port 8000 in the `/bin/wwww`.

In the express application I have crated a route in `routes/testAPI.js`,

```
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
    res.send(“API is working properly”);
});
```

And in app.js file I have used the route to handle request,

```
let testAPIRouter = require("./routes/testAPI");
app.use("/testAPI", testAPIRouter);
```

Now in the react application inside the App.js file I have called the API and updated the content of `<p>{this.state.apiresponse}</p>`.

App.js file,

```
class App extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state = {
          apiResponse : "",
       }
    }
    apiCall = () => {
       fetch("http://localhost:8000/testAPI")
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(res => this.setState({ apiResponse: res }));
    }
    componentWillMount = () => {
       this.callAPI();
    }
    
    render(){
        return(
          <div>
              <p>{this.state.apiResponse}</p>
          </div>
    )
   }
 }
```

My issue is to deploy this application on an apache server. As I'm running the express and react at different ports(3000 and 8000). I can build the react app using `npm run build` which will create static build files for react. But, how can I build the express app to use with react?
Is it so moving the express files to the server and always run the application there at port 8000?

I have successfully abled to run both at time using concurrent. I can run the application using `npm run dev`. But how to build the application and serve from apache?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the package.json of your react app use proxy

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8000"
```

and use only the routes not base url to fetch

```
fetch("/testAPI")
```

Now copy React App Folder to your Express folder
and add this scripts to your package.json of Express

```
"scripts": {
"client-install": "npm install --prefix reactapp",
"start": "node server.js",
"server": "nodemon server.js",
"client": "npm start --prefix reactapp",
"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
},
```

Now run

```
npm run client-install
```

for only one time And run

```
npm run dev
```

to run both server and client

Comment: I have tried this. In my case start is ./bin/www. But I'm getting an error says "sh: 1: concurrently: not found"

Comment: Now it's working fine. Concurrently was missing. How to build this to serve from apache?

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate all the answers I have received. So as an addition to the answers I have received I would like to mention how I moved the build into production.

```
1. npm install -g pm2
2. sudo chmod 755 /server/build/server.js (build file)
3. sudo pm2 start /server/build/server.js (Adds to pm2 task)
4. sudo pm2 startup systemd
```

And I have created a new virtual host in `/etc/apche2/sites-available/nodeapp.conf` and enable these apache modules
`sudo a2enmod proxy && sudo a2enmod proxy_http`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost(can be domain)

   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyVia Full
   <Proxy *>
      Require all granted
   </Proxy>

   <Location /node>
      ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3001
      ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3001
   </Location>

    <Directory "/project/server/build">
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now enable the site by `sudo a2ensite nodeapp.conf`. Reload the server and hit `localhost/node` and boom!

Incase if you are getting any blank screen error make sure add the below in react's package.json. `"homepage":"http://localhost/node"`.

https://www.ionos.com/community/server-cloud-infrastructure/nodejs/set-up-a-nodejs-app-for-a-website-with-apache-on-ubuntu-1604/

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your react application. Use [Env variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables) to use diffenrent URLS. Define your base url as ENV.

After a build it's just simple HTML, CSS, JS application you can deploy it on sub path as well.

ex. `https://example.com/website`

There is no need to deploy react on port or with Express.

But if you want to achieve something like this what you can do is
prepare a build, put it in express views folders and serve your react application from Express.